# Couldn't find World with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have a World parent object and a State child object. I'm trying to create a new State object and rails isn't finding the world id. I'm trying to link to the new state form from the world show page, and the url shows `.../worlds/1/states/new` so why is this not picking up on the parent id? The error is supposedly coming from this line in the controller `@world = World.find(params[:id])`. I have tried using `(params[:world_id])` even.

For brevity I'm only posting the relevant code here.

world.rb

```
class World < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :states
end
```

state.rb

```
class State < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :world
  belongs_to :user
end
```

states_controller.rb

```
class StatesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_state, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @states = State.all
  end

  def new
    @world = World.find(params[:id])
    @state = @world.states.build
  end

  def create
    @world = World.find(params[:id])
    @state = @world.states.build(state_params)
    @state.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @state.save
        format.html { redirect_to @state, notice: 'State was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_state
      @state = State.find(params[:id])
    end

    def state_params
      params.require(:state).permit(:name, :summary, :history, :population, :inception, :life_expectancy, :land_mass,
                                    :climate, :industry, :education, :mythology, :law, :culture, :world_id, :user_id)
    end
end
```

The link to the new state form in worlds/show.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to 'New State', new_world_state_path(@world) %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :states
  resources :worlds
  devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', sign_up: 'register' }
  root to: "home#index"

  resources :users
  resources :worlds do
    resources :states
  end
end
```

states/_form.html.erb

```
<div class="form">
  <%= form_for(state) do |f| %>
    <% if state.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(world.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this state from being saved:</h2>

        <ul>
        <% state.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Name' %><br />

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Basic Info</legend>
        <%= f.text_area :summary, placeholder: 'Summary About', rows: 6 %><br />
        <%= f.text_area :history, placeholder: 'History', rows: 6 %><br />
        <%= f.text_area :climate, placeholder: 'Climate', rows: 3 %><br />
        <%= f.text_area :industry, placeholder: 'Industry', rows: 3 %><br />
        <%= f.text_area :education, placeholder: 'Education', rows: 3 %><br />
        <%= f.text_area :culture, placeholder: 'Culture', rows: 3 %><br />
        <%= f.text_area :law, placeholder: 'Legal System, Crime & Punishment', rows: 3 %><br />
        <%= f.text_area :mythology, placeholder: 'Mythology', rows: 3 %><br />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Quick Stats</legend>
        <%= f.text_field :inception, placeholder: 'Inception' %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :population, placeholder: 'Population' %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :life_expectancy, placeholder: 'Ave. Life Expectance' %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :land_mass, placeholder: 'Land Mass' %><br />
    </fieldset>

    <p><%= f.submit %></p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

rails console results when clicking 'New State' link

```
Started GET "/worlds/1/states/new" for 70.196.17.76 at 2017-05-22 13:43:47 +0000
Cannot render console from 70.196.17.76! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by StatesController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"world_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  World Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "worlds".* FROM "worlds" WHERE "worlds"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find World with 'id'=):

app/controllers/states_controller.rb:13:in `new'
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (4.7ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.6ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (36.6ms)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your `link_to` helper to specify and tell to Rails what's the parameter you're sending through it:

From:

```
<%= link_to 'New State', new_world_state_path(@world) %>
```

To:

```
<%= link_to 'New State', new_world_state_path(id: @world) %>
```

`id` because you're trying to find the `World` through `:id` as param.

Try also changing the `param` that's being received within the controller where you're setting the `@world` variable:

```
def new
  @world = World.find(params[:world_id])
  ...
end
```

In the `show.html.erb`:

```
<%= link_to 'New World', new_world_state_path(world_id: @world) %>
```

**Update**: What we made:

In the `app/views/worlds/show.html.erb` to change the way the param was being setted:

From:

```
<%= link_to 'New Nation', new_world_state_path(world_id: @world_id) %> # @world_id wasn't defined
```

To:

```
<%= link_to 'New Nation', new_world_state_path(world_id: @world.id) %>
```

In the `/app/views/states/_form.html.erb` to add the `world_id` as a `hidden_field`:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :world_id, value: @world.id %>
```

And then in `app/controllers/states_controller.rb` to change the way the params were being received:

```
def new
  @world = World.find(params[:world_id])
  @state = @world.states.build
end

def create
  @world = World.find(params[:state][:world_id])
  ...
```

Comment: I get No route matches ```{:action=>"new", :controller=>"states", :id=>#<World id: 1, ... (every value in the world 1 entry) } missing required keys: [:world_id]```.

Comment: do you mind posting the params shown in the rails console when you click on the `New State` link ?.

Comment: I also tried to use ```<%= link_to 'New State', new_world_state_path(@world_id) %>``` and ```...path(@world.world_id)``` but those are both very wrong.

Comment: Edited my question to include the console stuff.

Comment: yeah, the parameter is `world_id `, you should be able to get it from there.

Comment: Change it from `id` in the `link_to` helper to `world_id` in both cases, the view and the controller.

Comment: What do you mean by this: ```And be sure the link_to is inside the each block in order to get a value to send through it:```? I don't have a loop on my show page.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were doing it inside an `each` block, as you wrote _worlds/show/index.html.erb_, I got confused, anyways, passing the object should be enough to get the id.

Comment: My apologies, I did not realize I had mistyped that part. It's the show.html.erb page. I agree, passing the object should be working, I have no idea why it isn't.

Comment: [Here](https://bitbucket.org/hnhm/world) there's a repo I think working the same way as your. If you need it we can move the discussion to a chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144845/discussion-between-janden-hale-and-sebastian-palma).

Answer (score 2):

The world_id while it is passed to the :new action, it may not be passed back on the form to the create action.

Your state_params are expecting a :world_id to be sent back so add a hidden field to send it back on the form.

new.html.erb

```
<%= f.hidden_field :world_id, :value => @world.id %>
```

and update the create action to

```
@world = World.find(params[:world_id])
```

Comment: That got me past the new action and finally showed the form, but after submitting the form I'm getting the same error. ```Couldn't find World with 'id'=```